# Error 502 proxy error (network name no longer available)

Tags: c#, wcf, proxy

I have an application that connects to a external WCF Service behind a proxy.

When i try to call a method of the server I keep receiving the following error:

```
(502) Proxy Error ( The specified network name is no longer available.  ).
```

With an exception of type ProtocolException.

I have tried to search for the WSDL using a browser (using the same proxy as the application) and I am able to reach it without problems.

The proxy is specified in the app.config under *system.net/defaultProxy*.

Thanks in advance.

Mattias

Comment: does the WCF service that you are trying to access works Certificate based security?

Comment: Security mode is set to none.